# If $\sin^4(x)=A+B\cos(2x)+C\cos(4x)$, then find $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin^4(x)=A+B\cos(2x)+C\cos(4x)$, then find $A, B$, and $C$.

Would I use half-angle identities for this problem?

Comment: Yes you would, have you tried that?

Comment: I think you need double angle property.

Comment: Yes I have, I guess I have been struggling setting it up. Thank you for confirming!

Answer (score 8):

No, just take $x=0,\pi/4,\pi/2$, and you'll get three equations on $A,B,C$:
\begin{align}
0&=A+B+C\\ \ \\
\frac14&=A+0-C\\ \\
1&=A-B+C
\end{align}
Solving, we get $A=3/8$, $B=-1/2$, $C=1/8$.

Comment: But that would not prove that the $A, B, C$ found actually satisfy the given condition for all x.

Comment: Of course. But the question doesn't require that: it says, "if the equality holds..." If such $A,B,C$ exist, they will be the ones given by the system of three equations. Proving that they exist is a different thing, although it is trivial: since the three functions are linearly independent, there is a single way of writing the constant function 1 as a linear combination of them.

Answer (score 2):

By the double-angle formula for $\cos{2x}$,
$$ \cos{2x} = \cos^2{x} - \sin^2{x} = 2\cos^2{x}-1 = 1-2\sin^2{x}. $$
Rearranging,
$$ \sin^2{x} = \frac{1}{2}(1-\cos{2x}). $$
Squaring both sides an expanding,
$$ \sin^4{x} = \frac{1}{4}(1-2\cos{2x}+\cos^2{2x}), $$
and then using the double-angle formula $\cos{4x} = 2\cos^2{x}-1 $ gives
$$ \sin^4{x} = \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\cos{2x}+\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos{4x}) = \frac{3}{8} - \frac{1}{2}\cos{2x}+\frac{1}{8}\cos{4x}. $$

---

Alternatively,
$$ \sin^4{x} = \frac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^4}{2^4i^4} = \frac{1}{16}(e^{4ix} - 4e^{2ix} + 6 - 4e^{-2ix} + e^{-4ix} ) = \frac{1}{8}(\cos{4x}-4\cos{2x}+3). $$